# Creating a REST api to send data to the frontend

Tags: react-native, backend

I was thinking about some projects that I could do, and I came with the idea of building a books app in React native. To start, I wanted the user to get a list of all the books and the ability to get the details about each book and some other things. But I'm completely new on the backend, and my doubt is: 
Should i use the features of the backend, such as a database or should I just create a simple serve that only sends a JSON to the frontend?

Comment: Since this sounds like practice: Use a database. Hardcoding some JSON sounds like a perfect recipe for headache.

Comment: I tought about that, but how I'm gonna get this data? because, in this app(for now) the only thing that I'm going to do is get all books. To use a database I would have to get this data from somewhere.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid hardcoding things like you suggested, but I think that, in this case I don´t have so many options...

Comment: Inserting the stuff into a database or hardcoding isn't that different, you just store it in a different way? I admit I can't follow you here. You have to define the data at some point.

Comment: You're right. I think that I'll try to store it in a database and see how I'll use it in the frontend

Answer (score -1):

You should use a database as it is more flexible and easier to manage, and using any backend framework to forward your data in json format to your frontend, I would suggest mysql server and slim php framework